# Back end Ruby then which technology used for Front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, background, frontend

i am newbie to web technology, i have fair knowledge about the various technologies, but at that depth.

I like to asked the question is, If i tried to design my website backend with Ruby then for designing the front end which web technology i prefer? Or HTML5 supports for Ruby?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check out http://rubyonrails.org/. Run and grab http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Comment: What are the front end technologies do you have as an option?

Comment: if you mean 'frontend' you mean web? so there are several frameworks for that written in ruby like rails, sinatra, camping. have a look at the ruby-toolbox: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_app_frameworks.html

Comment: Is it possible to front end with HTML5 Like HTML,CSS and JavaScript with rails in backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a Ruby web development framework for your site then you have multiple choices.  The most popular framework for developing a site is [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).
Another popular framework is [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). And the newest kid on the block as of this writing, [Pakyow](http://pakyow.com/). I believe all of them support HTML 5.